# how to create drop down list to select month and year

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create drop down select list for select month and year in full calendar using below code:

`var momObj = moment([your date string]);`

If each option in your select box has a value of a date, (I would suggest the first of each month), then all you would have to do is pass FullCalendar the selected value.

`[your calendar].fullCalendar('gotoDate', [selected value]);`

This will send your calendar to the selected date.

Comment: It is not difficult to build a drop down select for months and years. What have you tried (post your code), and where are you having difficulties? You have to attempt a solution yourself; we aren't here to just write code for you for free.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<select class="form-control bt_select" name="month" id="month">
  <option value="">Select Month</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getMonth(),
    h = d.getFullYear();

var monthArray = new Array();
monthArray[0] = "January";
monthArray[1] = "February";
monthArray[2] = "March";
monthArray[3] = "April";
monthArray[4] = "May";
monthArray[5] = "June";
monthArray[6] = "July";
monthArray[7] = "August";
monthArray[8] = "September";
monthArray[9] = "October";
monthArray[10] = "November";
monthArray[11] = "December";
for(m = 0; m <= 11; m++) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = monthArray[m];
    // server side month start from one
    optn.value = (m+1);

    // if specific month selected
    if ( m == 0) {
        optn.selected = true;

    }
    if( m > n )
    {
        optn.disabled = true;
    }

    document.getElementById('month').options.add(optn);
}
</script>
```

To create Year dropdown:

```
  <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control bt_select">
      <option value="">Select Year</option>
  </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
for(y = 2016; y <= 2025; y++) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = y;
    optn.value = y;
    if(y > h)
        optn.disabled = true;

    // if specific-year is 2015 selected
    if (y == 2015) {
        optn.selected = true;
    }

    document.getElementById('year').options.add(optn);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use [jQuery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );`

Comment: how to use it in full calendar header field. i want to take input from user like drop down list..